# ReferenceError: msg is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, command, bots

Hello i wanted to mentions the user that are running the command but i am getting a Error

Here is the Code!

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
 
module.exports = {
  name: 'not-dropping',
  description: 'sets the dropping status!',
  
  execute(message, args) {
    if (message.channel.id === '1059798572855476245') {
      message.delete(1000);
      
      const name = ("dropping-")
      message.channel.setName(name)
      message.channel.send(`Successfully set the dropping status to **${name}**\n<@${msg.author.id}> is not Dropping anymore!\nDont Ping Him in your Ticket.`)
    }
  }
}
```

I do not understand waht the Problem is

Answer (score 1):

As the error states "msg" is not defined.

In the code "{msg.author.id}" you are using msg while the actual variable is "message".

Change it to {message.author.id}

Answer (score 0):

"msg" There is no such use

You should use "message"

**I changed where you need to change in the code :)**

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
 
module.exports = {
  name: 'not-dropping',
  description: 'sets the dropping status!',
  
  execute(message, args) {
    if (message.channel.id === '1059798572855476245') {
      message.delete(1000);
      
      const name = ("dropping-")
      message.channel.setName(name)
      message.channel.send(`Successfully set the dropping status to **${name}**\n<@${message.author.id}> is not Dropping anymore!\nDont Ping Him in your Ticket.`)
    }
  }
}
```